# Can "Drag and Drop" and "Scrolling" work well at the same time?

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to have drag and drop and scrolling at the same time? It seems a bit flakey if you simply enable it. Sometimes it scrolls; sometimes it drag and drops. 
Would be nice if could manually invoke a drag from long pointer or something?

My code has a `Container` that is drop-enabled and y-scrollable. It has drag enabled `Components` within it. Is there something else I can do to make them play nicely together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can but if you touch a draggable component it will drag. You can toggle these modes thru long press or any other flag by flicking the draggable flags dynamically.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work.  I called setDraggable(true); in the longPress function but that doesn't instigate an instant drag. It just means next time I click it I can drag it. Is there a way of initiating the component into dragging mode?

Comment: No. But you can fake it. Once you set draggable true just invoke form.pointerPressed(x, y) then a couple of pointerDragged calls and a drag should effectively be initiated. Its a hack but should work.

Comment: Ah, so simple. I had tried calling the control's `pointerPressed` but not the form's one. That works very well.